# Multiple variables equal to same value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is't there a way set multiple variables equal to same value in Swift?
like:

```
self.view1.backgroundColor = .white
self.view2.backgroundColor = .white
self.view3.backgroundColor = .white
```

make it into one line

```
self.view1.backgroundColor, self.view2.backgroundColor, self.view3.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this, if you *must* use a one-liner:

```
[view1, view2, view3].forEach { $0.backgroundColor = .white }
```

Comment: thanks. can `self.label.textColor = .white self.view2.backgroundColor = .white` use this way?

Comment: @0x0 you could add a `;`, so `self.label.textColor = .white; self.view2.backgroundColor = .white`. But just split it into 2 lines instead... try to avoid `;` in Swift.