# Change multiple subsequent variables in swift

Tags: swift, variables

I was making a shop but to show which background is selected I stumbled into a weird hick up. Is there a way to change multiple variables in a loop so that for example:

```
var achtergrondSelected1:Int = 1
var achtergrondSelected2:Int = 0
var achtergrondSelected3:Int = 0
var achtergrondSelected4:Int = 0
var achtergrondSelected5:Int = 0
var achtergrondSelected6:Int = 0
```

(Instead of a boolean my old code used 1 and 0, same effect)
Let's say the person selects background (= achtergrond) 4, at the moment I'm changing all values manually, but is there a way to create a loop that uses the number in the name to change the values to 0 who need to be 0 and 1 who need to be one?

Comment: As a beginner, what about using only one `Int` value, and let it be 0 for `achtergrondSelected1`, 1 for `achtergrondSelected2`? This way, you know which one is "selected" and so the others aren't. Now, in fact, you should then use a `enum` which would give you which one is selected.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720878/14351818

Comment: Why aren't you using an `Array`?

Comment: when I try to use an array Xcode prohibits me to use variables inside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid to declare N variables and loops, **you can just use an enum**.

```
enum achtergrondSelected : Int
{
    case achterground1
    case achterground2
    case achterground3
    case achterground4
    case achterground5
}

var selectedBackground : achtergrondSelected
selectedBackground = .achterground1
print(selectedBackground.rawValue)
```

For cases name I choose "achterground" like it was in your example, but you can obviously choose other names.
I hope that's what you was looking for.